# ReadProcessMemory doesnt work correctly

Tags: visual-c++

I have a problem with the ReadProcessMemory function in c++. Actually the function itself works fine but when it comes to larger addresses (for example when I use ungsigned __int64 instead of DWORD since DWORD is too small for the Address) the function gives me a wrong pointer address. Here is the relevant code:

```
DWORD tempAddress;
unsigned __int64 potentialBasePointerAddress = 0x13F8A0000 + 0x18606B8; //I used unsigned __int64 since 0x13F8A0000 is too large for DWORD

if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)potentialBasePointerAddress, &tempAddress, sizeof(tempAddress), NULL))
{
    cout << tempAddress << endl;
}
//in this specific case the tempAddress is 1BD5679 (or 29185657) but actually it should be 3E7D4FE0 (see (*))
```

[(*)Cheat Engine Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlgDU.png)

If I change  DWORD tempAddress; to unsigned __int64 tempAddress; the tempAddress is 1953A4A0002C88A5 (or 18249832811198240377)

I have really no clue how to solve this problem. I am pretty sure there is a way to handle Base Addresses larger than DWORD size but I am too stupid to find out...

I am thankful for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you compiling the program as a 64-bit binary? If you are compiling it as a 32-bit then the cast to `LPVOID` actually truncates your pointer to 32-bit value and thus you simply read the wrong address.